# I own too few ripples to buy ripples (have only 87xrp, want to buy 7,000)

Tags: ripple

I have 87 ripples.  When I use the ripple client to purchase additional ripples, I'm unable to and get an error saying the network isn't available.

I can only guess this is because I have too few ripples to complete the transaction.

- How do I get a few more ripples to complete my transaction?

Reference wallet ID: rPZhwqx7kQdssJD6i3cnEpd9kQ1Tofzjkx

Comment: How are you trying to purchase additional ripples? Are you trying to make an XRP payment to yourself and pay with another currency? Or are you trying to buy with an offer that takes an existing offer? Or are you trying to place an offer for someone else to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was just that the network was down.

You have enough for your two lines of trust for BTC and USD.

(reserve = 50 and trust lines 12.5 each, so  50 + 12.5 + 12.5 = 75)

You should be able to trade your BTC for XRP.

The network is up now.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think thats the reason because if it where that would mean the ripple network had more then a 1.2% fee (87/7000 = 0.0124) and on [the ripple website](https://ripple.com/) they say the fee is only $0.0001 which now that I think about it seems odd that they would give the value in dollars but hey, what do I know. So at the current rate of $0.04 per ripple (as of 7/8/13) the fee is 0.25% of a ripple (0.0001 / 0.04 = 0.0025).

Also that would make the fee `24X` more then the bitcoin network (0.012 / 0.0005 = 24, 0.0005 is the minimum btc transaction fee) which seems equally outrages.

I know that [bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/) sells ripples for USD so you might want to just consider buying them there.